# Split with string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, split, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem with a quick function I wrote for splitting Sharepoint specific ids ({id};#{name}):

```
function GetOnlyValue {
param( 
[string] $fullValue
)

if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($fullValue))
{
    # On regarde si on a la valeur
    if($fullValue -Like "*;#*")
    {
        $array = $fullValue -split ";#", 2, "simplematch"

        return $array[-1]
    }
}

return $fullValue
}
```

But this function does half the job because, for instance, when I pass a value formated like that : myId;#myName the function return me this value: "#myName" instead of "myName".

Thanks for your help !

06/02/2016 EDIT: This function is included in a module that I import in a script. I use it in correlation with a Sharepoint 2013 site, browsing each SPListItem of a SPList:

```
$formation = GetOnlyValue -fullValue $spItem["Formation"]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce here. `'myId;#myName' -split ';#',2,'simplematch'` works as expected.

Comment: I used simple and double quotes, I've always the same result :/

Comment: try to output `$spItem["Formation"]` and ensure its a string

Comment: Hi, so it works now, by ensuring the data is a string -__- : `GetOnlyValue -fullValue ([string]$item["Formation"])` Thanks to all for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, but you can simplify your script using a `-replace`:

```
function GetOnlyValue {
    param( 
        [string] $fullValue
    )

    $fullValue -replace '^.*#'
}
```

Comment: Again, it cut at the ';' but not at the ';#' group.Thanks anyway !

Comment: For instance: 457;#FirstName LastName  - Organization. I have in output: #FirstName LastName  - Organization

Comment: I have in output `FirstName LastName - Organization.`

Comment: Note that your code is not identical to what they have in their question. For a string containing *two* `#` yours would remove everything up to the second, whilst theirs would split at the first.

Comment: yes, to fix that he had to make the dot non greedy (`^.*?#')

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex with capture groups:

```
function GetOnlyValue
{
    Param
    ( 
        [string]$fullValue
    )

    if($fullValue -match '(.*);#(.*)'){
        $Matches[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really a reason for that; their code should work fine. Not everything needs to be bashed at with regexes, especially if the code is not broken to begin with.

Comment: @Joey Yep, so it's up to OP to decide. I'm merely suggesting.

Comment: Nope, even with the regex, I have the problem